# Splitting an array into columns in Athena/Presto

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I feel this should be simple, but I've struggled to find the right terminology, please bear with me.

I have two columns, `timestamp` and `voltages` which is the array

If I do a simple

```
SELECT timestamp, voltages FROM table
```

Then I'd get a result of:

`|timestamp |        voltages          |
|1544435470 |3.7352,3.749,3.7433,3.7533|
|1544435477 |3.7352,3.751,3.7452,3.7533|
|1544435484 |3.7371,3.749,3.7433,3.7533|
|1544435490 |3.7352,3.749,3.7452,3.7533|
|1544435497 |3.7352,3.751,3.7452,3.7533|
|1544435504 |3.7352,3.749,3.7452,3.7533|`

But I want to split the `voltages` array so each element in its array is its own column.

`|timestamp  |  v1   |  v2  |   v3  |  v4  |
|1544435470 |3.7352 |3.749 |3.7433  |3.7533|
|1544435477 |3.7352 |3.751 |3.7452  |3.7533|
|1544435484 |3.7371 |3.749 |3.7433  |3.7533|
|1544435490 |3.7352 |3.749 |3.7452  |3.7533|
|1544435497 |3.7352 |3.751 |3.7452  |3.7533|
|1544435504 |3.7352 |3.749 |3.7452  |3.7533|`

I know I can do this with:

```
SELECT timestamp, voltages[1] as v1, voltages[2] as v2 FROM table
```

But I'd need to be able to do this programmatically, as opposed to listing them out.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Daniel, SQL is statically typed. Number of result columns need to be known before query is executed, so there can be no `v1, v2, ...` (depending on actual length of the arrays).
Having said that, you can still "programatically" generate SQL. But you can't have SQL alone do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I was wondering that, but I thought if that was the case there might be a way to do it with a secondary query on the result of the first. Hmmm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [athena presto - multiple columns from long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142257/athena-presto-multiple-columns-from-long-to-wide)

Answer (score 3):

This should serve your purpose if you have arrays of fixed length.
You need to first break down each array element into it's own row. You can do this using the `UNNEST` operator in the following way :

```
SELECT timestamp, volt
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(voltages) AS t(volt)
```

Using the resultant table you can pivot (convert multiple rows with the same timestamp into multiple columns) by referring to Gordon Linoff's answer for "[need to convert data in multiple rows with same ID into 1 row with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726154/3234357)".

Comment: Thanks for that, interesting approach. At the moment I don't know the array length upfront. Do you see this having any advantages over the last method in my question? I'd say the element addressing is clearer to understand, but I don't know if your suggested method has other benefits.