# How can I unnest a JSON field keeping them on the same records?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, pivot, amazon-athena

Assuming that I have a json field extracted as array that looks like

```
{{priceCurrency=Euro,price=16.99,validInRegion=Netherlands},
{priceCurrency=Euro,price=16.99,validInRegion=Spain},
{priceCurrency=Pound Sterling,price=15.0,validInRegion=Great Britain}}
```

How can I unnest it based on some of its values (currency, region etc), without splitting it into different records?

Using `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` what I achieved is the following:

```
> Product   |  priceCurrency   |  price   |    priceRegion
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> 1         |      Euro        |  16.99   |  Netherlands              
> 1         |      Euro        |  16.99   |  Spain     
> 1         |      Pound       |  15.0    |  Great Britain 
> 2         |      ...         |   ...    |       ...      
> 2         |      ...         |   ...    |       ...
```

While I want to achieve this:

```
> Product   |  currencyNL   |  priceNL   |    currencyGB   |  priceGB  |  currencyES  |  priceES
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 1         |    Euro       |  16.99     |       Pound     |   15.0    |    Euro      |  16.99  
> 2         |    ...        |   ...      |        ...      |    ...    |     ...      |   ...
```

Comment: You need to first make sure that your JSON is valid: https://pastebin.com/V6ykF4nb

Comment: Question: Do you have the country codes stored somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your comments Eddy. You are right about JSON's validity. Consider it as a simplified extraction of the original JSON. Regarding your 2nd comment lets assume that I can have them stored somewhere, as these codes are predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pre-defined lists of currencies (and a valid JSON array), you can `unnest`, then use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    t.product,
    max(case when x.obj.validInRegion = 'Netherlands' then x.obj.priceCurrency) currencyNL,
    max(case when x.obj.validInRegion = 'Netherlands' then x.obj.price) priceNL,
    max(case when x.obj.validInRegion = 'Great Britain' then x.obj.priceCurrency) currencyGB,
    max(case when x.obj.validInRegion = 'Great Britain' then x.obj.price) priceGB,
    ...
from mytable t
cross join unnest(t.js_column) as x(obj)
group by t.product
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to generate columns from rows except to explicitly list them all like GMB suggests in their answer (also see [Athena/Presto - UNNEST MAP to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876977/athena-presto-unnest-map-to-columns/62915660#62915660)). You can, however, aggregate to a map like in this
answer: [athena presto - multiple columns from long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142257/athena-presto-multiple-columns-from-long-to-wide/63172644#63172644) – with that method you could get a result like this:

```
Product | Prices
--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | {Netherlands_Euro=>16.99, Spain_Euro=>16.99, Great Britain_Pound=>15.0}
2       | {…}
```

It would probably be possible to do a multi-level aggregation and get something like the following too:

```
Product | Prices
--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | {Netherlands=>{Euro=>16.99}, Spain=>{Euro=>16.99}, {Great Britain=>{Pound=>15.0}}
2       | {…}
```

Exactly how to do this would depend on your query. There are more details in  [athena presto - multiple columns from long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142257/athena-presto-multiple-columns-from-long-to-wide/63172644#63172644)